# Disassemble a Dynamic Link Library with OllyDbg

Tags: dll, reverse-engineering, ollydbg

Is there a option I can choose how to launch the **DLL**(like when debugging a dll project in visual studio)?

As it seems to me when I drop the **DLL** into OD,the only option I have is to launch it by `LOADDLL.EXE`, is that the whole story?

Answer (score 3):

You can't run a DLL by itself, it has to be loaded by some process. OllyDbg provides Loaddll.exe just for that purpose, or you can just debug whatever application is supposed to load it and enable break on new module.

Comment: How to `enable break on new module` if one doesn't know which function of the module is actually called?

Comment: The debugger will be stopped for each module loaded; once you see your DLL, trace the code to see which functions the caller uses.